# Inverse implicit function theorem

Tags: implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice continuously differentiable function such that $f(0,0)=0$ and $f_{y}(0,0)\ne 0$.
>
> By the implicit function theorem, there exists an $\epsilon >0$ and a continuously differentiable function $\psi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi(0)=0$ and $f(x,\psi(x))=0$ for all $x \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.
>
> Using the function $\psi$ constructed above, prove that the mapping
> $$F(x,w)=\left(x+wf_{x}(x,\psi(x)),\psi(x)+wf_{y}(x,\psi(x) \right)$$ is one-to-one in a neighbourhood of the origin $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I tried to use the inverse function theorem. If I can show that $\det JF|_{(0,0)}\ne 0$, then the result will follow. The inverse function theorem  says that, assuming $F$ is continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of the origin, if $\det JF \ne 0$ at the origin, then $F$ has a smooth inverse in some open neighbourhood of the origin, so in particular, it is one-to-one.$$\det JF(x,w)=\begin{vmatrix}
1+w \cdot \left(f_{xx}(x,\psi(x))+f_{xy}(x,\psi(x))\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x) \right) & f_{x}(x,\psi(x)) \\
\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)+w \cdot \left(f_{yx}(x,\psi(x))+f_{yy}(x,\psi(x))\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\right)& f_{y}(x,\psi(x))
\end{vmatrix}$$Moreover there is a hint in the question, which is to use $\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)=-\frac{f_x(x,\psi(x))}{f_y(x,\psi(x))}$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you replace $\psi'$ by its value in your Jacobian matrix? Maybe it will be clearer, the you compute directly the determinant. And what is $f_x$? is it $\partial_x f$?

Answer (score 1):

You have computed $\det JF$ for *general* $(x, w)$. To apply the inverse function theorem in the way you describe, you just need to evaluate $\det JF$ at the *specific point* $(x, w) = (0, 0)$, and check that the answer is non-zero.

If you do this, you find that
\begin{align} \det JF(0,0) &=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & f_{x}(0,0)\\
\frac{d\psi}{dx}(0)& f_{y}(0,0)
\end{vmatrix} \\ & = f_{y}(0,0) - \frac{d\psi}{dx}(0) \times f_{x}(0,0) \\ &=  f_{y}(0,0) +  \frac{f_{x}(0,0)^2}{f_y(0,0)} \\ &= \frac{f_y(0,0)^2 + f_x(0,0)^2 }{f_y(0,0)}\\ & \neq 0. \end{align}

(In this calculation, I used the facts that $\psi(0) = 0$ and $f_y(0, 0) \neq 0$.)

Comment: Thank you for your effort.How did you conclude those many terms are zero?Which are zero and why?

Comment: We want to show that $\det JF (0,0)$ is **non**-zero. In my final expression, the numerator is a sum of two squares, $f_y^2 + f_x^2$. We know that $f_y^2 > 0$ and $f_x^2 \geq 0$, so...

Comment: Yes but how did you conclude the 2*2 matrix with those terms?Did you take $f_{xx}=0?$ or $f_{xy}=0$?

Comment: I substituted $x=0$ and $w=0$ into your expression for $\det JF(x,w)$.

Comment: So to be clear: the complicated-looking terms involving $f_{xx}, f_{xy}$ and $f_{yy}$ are all multiplied by a factor of $w$. When I substituted $w=0$, those terms all disappeared!